# json.loads does not keep double quotes intact

Tags: python, json, string

When I use `json.loads`, it converts double quotes into single quotes.
This is troubling me, can someone help in clarifying this?

```
>>> import simplesjson as json
>>> string = '{"created_at": "2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800"}'
>>> json.loads(string,'utf-8')
{'created_at': '2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800'}
```

I understand that this is a normal behavior and i can tweak my code easily. But thinking whether same can be achieved or not?

Comment: This is *normal behaviour*. Python strings can use both single and double quotes. The quotes are *not part of the value*.

Comment: Remember that these are objects in memory and python is showing you a serialized text version of the objects for humans to view, not the objects themselves.

Comment: It matters in my app, that's why i asked.
I could have tweaked my result anyhow. Don't know why so many downvotes!!!! i guess you guys need to be clear on what type of question needs downvote.

Comment: If the quotes are having an effect please explain why, otherwise there's no question here. Python treats single and double quotes as interchangeable, so what's causing an issue for you?

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted...this is a pretty legitimate question for newcomers to python who are expecting it to comply with JSON behaviour and IMO the point of SO. What's with the elitist attitude guys?? I have to send this json data from a python server on to other apps expecting JSON standard and this behaviour is clearly not conforming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: quotes are *not part of the value*. They are part of the syntax, signalling to the parser that a string is defined.

JSON only supports double quotes, but in *Python*, strings can be defined using either single or double quotes. When echoing a string value, Python reflects the value by showing you Python syntax to redefine the same value. For this representation single quotes are preferred. Only if the value actually contains at least one single quote and no double quotes would double quotes be used:

```
>>> "Normal strings are reflected with single quotes by Python"
'Normal strings are reflected with single quotes by Python'
>>> 'Single quote: \''
"Single quote: '"
>>> 'Single quote: \', and a double quote: \"'
'Single quote: \', and a double quote: "'
```

What is you see is *entirely normal behaviour*. You can't change this; the output you see is a debugging tool. Produce your own formatter if this is something you want to change.

When you produce JSON from the Python structure again, only double quotes will be used to produce valid JSON output:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_string = '{"created_at": "2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800"}'
>>> json.loads(json_string)
{u'created_at': u'2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800'}
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(json_string))
'{"created_at": "2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800"}'
```

Comment: I understand your words here above. For inserting data into MongoDB by python SDK, the data need to be in dict format. But while inserting with json.loads above the quotes are posing error(as in my case). I can tweak my process a little, but i thought of asking it whether it can be done or not

Comment: @Shrey: PyMongo lets you work with native Python types, and will encode to and from JSON for you. You should never have to use `json.loads()` there.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I should also use the same structure as Shrey. There is an error when sending json as a single quote to ElasticSearch. How can I solve it?

Comment: @horoyoio Elasticsearch is not PyMongo, Shrey didn’t have the same problem.   Single quotes are not part of the JSON syntax. Encore your dictionary to JSON when sending it to Elasticsearch.