# JSON Download Changes " Double Quotes To ' Single Quotes

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a simple python 3.6 program that downloads an AWS S3 JSON file using the Boto3 library

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

content_object = s3.Object('my-bucket-name', 'folder1/folder2/emr-config.json')
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)

print(json_content)
```

But the program is changing the " double quotes used in the JSON file to ' single quotes i.e., when I download the file directly from the AWS Management Console the JSON uses " double quotes but when I run my program and print out the resulting JSON it uses ' single quotes.

```
[{'Properties': {'maximizeResourceAllocation': 'true'}, 'Classification': 'spark'}]
```

*versus*

```
[{"Properties": {"maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"}, "Classification": "spark"}]
```

This is a configuration file I will be using for my EMR Cluster creation and it only works if the JSON configuration uses " double quotes.

I'd like to find a solution that doesn't involve me doing a find-and-replace on the entire file. Is there a way for me to download the file in the " double quotes form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the JSON string via Python, why bother deserializing it to an object? You could just write file_contents as is and it'll stay as valid JSON

Answer (score 3):

reffering from: [json.loads does not keep double quotes intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002211/json-loads-does-not-keep-double-quotes-intact)

First of all: quotes are *not part of the value*. They are part of the syntax, signalling to the parser that a string is defined.

JSON only supports double quotes, but in *Python*, strings can be defined using either single or double quotes. When echoing a string value, Python reflects the value by showing you Python syntax to redefine the same value. For this representation single quotes are preferred. Only if the value actually contains at least one single quote and no double quotes would double quotes be used:

```
>>> "Normal strings are reflected with single quotes by Python"
'Normal strings are reflected with single quotes by Python'
>>> 'Single quote: \''
"Single quote: '"
>>> 'Single quote: \', and a double quote: \"'
'Single quote: \', and a double quote: "'
```

What is you see is *entirely normal behaviour*. You can't change this; the output you see is a debugging tool. Produce your own formatter if this is something you want to change.

When you produce JSON from the Python structure again, only double quotes will be used to produce valid JSON output:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_string = '{"created_at": "2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800"}'
>>> json.loads(json_string)
{u'created_at': u'2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800'}
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(json_string))
'{"created_at": "2012/02/05 04:03:50 -0800"}'
```